# Points appear on map google python code

Tags: python, google-maps, html, point, pygmaps

I'm using python to develop a map (Google Maps) and add some points in specific location. After searching I found it can be done using *pygmaps*. So I installed it using `pip`, then I wrote this code and I need to add points and open a webpage for the map find the points there.

```
import pygmaps 
import webbrowser 
mymap = pygmaps.maps(37.428, -122.145, 16)
mymap.setgrids(37.42, 37.43, 0.001, -122.15, -122.14, 0.001)
mymap.addpoint(37.427, -122.145, "#0000FF") 
mymap.addradpoint(37.429, -122.145, 95, "#FF0000")
path = [(37.429, -122.145),(37.428, -122.145),(37.427, -122.145),(37.427, -122.146),(37.427, -122.146)] mymap.addpath(path,"#00FF00") 
mymap.draw('./mymap.draw.html') 
url = url = './mymap.draw.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

I didn't see the points, only the map.

Comment: Please re-format your post first. You can't expect anyone to look at this untidy mess of a post in-depth. Put your code samples inside the appropriate editor tags.

Comment: Sigh... Click on 'edit'. Then click on "Code Sample" in the editor. Copy and paste your code so it stands where 'enter your code here' stands. Pay attention to the indentation of the code.

Comment: http://bit.ly/how-to-ask-a-question

Answer (score 3):

Changing

```
mymap.draw('./mymap.draw.html') 
url = url = './mymap.draw.html'
```

to

```
mymap.draw('mymap.draw.html') 
url = 'mymap.draw.html'
```

worked for me.

Edit: added screenshot.

[image]

Comment: work u means u c the points ?!! if yup is they are clear to be seeen :=) :D becaause i didnot c :(

Comment: i didnt c points and i increase the radius circle but stiill :( dont c any thing

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. The points are near Palo Alto, CA, USA, I see the grid too.

Comment: Do you see the grid? Are you looking at Palo Alto?

Comment: If u please can u send me print screen shoot for it to search for it !! at niga_hisham89@hotmail.com thank in advance

Comment: i didnt see the grid in other words i'm not sure if this the grid !! And i'm looking @ Palo Alto now in the left is university south and in the right is triple EL

Comment: I added the screenshot to my post. You can save it to your harddrive and have a look at it in the original size I saved it in.

Comment: oh its dont appear to me !! how came the same code for me appear nothing and u appear thing grid and point

Comment: Did u add any thing in the code ?!!! could u plz copy paste me ur code and tell me if there any other thing i suppose to doo !!!! i'm really feeling lost that it didnt appear to me

Comment: I copied your code from your post. I only changed the output filename as I wrote before. I have the pygmaps package from here: http://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/ . Make sure you use that version. You might also want to check your javascript settings (because pygmaps just generates javascript). Try to open the file with google chrome browser and look under the tools/developer-tools in the "script" tab. Firefox also has the very handy firebugs extension that works similarly. How do you execute your python script? Maybe you catch exceptions somewhere and do nothing to handle them?

Comment: i use Internet Explorer .. yup i download this and i'm using activepython  so i just install it using pip install http:// .... /
and i excutee python as if i'm execting a normall file f5 !! i didnt knw how to work with scripts in that case !! can u please help me

Comment: I don't know anything about activepython, sorry. It's kinda hard to help here. Why don't you try what I wrote in my last comment. Maybe also try to work with the mainline python distribution (I am using version 2.7).

Comment: ok tell me please after download pygmaps what to do which file to run how to excute it !!

Comment: ohhh thankks soo muchh it perfectly work withhh google chromne =) seems that Internet explorel is just oldest :D !! thank in advanceee

Comment: That is a question for a different post. But before you ask that question on Stackoverflow, please have a look at a beginners tutorial.  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html or 'A byte of Python' etc.

Comment: Oh? great! Anyhow, if you want to do serious development I strongly recommend to read a nice tutorial so you can take full advantage of all of Python's features.